# Asignar un valor a una columna en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla y deseo sacar unas estadisticas. Cuando hago la consulta no me trae el nombre, solo me trae el valor.
[image: Tabla con los valores originales]

[image: Tabla de resultados]

En la segunda tabla deberia decirme "Altura signif del oleaje(m)" en vez del valor que sale.

```
 SELECT `Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`, year(`Fecha (GMT)`)*100+month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Fecha,month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Mes, avg(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as Promedio, variance(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as Varianza, stddev(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as Desviacion_tipica, std(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as Desviacion_estandar, min(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as Minimo, max(`Altura Signif del Oleaje(m)`) as maximo FROM prueba2.arousa_wave_marea_sol
group by 2
union all
SELECT `Periodo Medio(s)`, year(`Fecha (GMT)`)*100+month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Fecha,month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Mes, avg(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as Promedio, variance(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as Varianza, stddev(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as Desviacion_tipica, std(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as Desviacion_estandar, min(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as Minimo, max(`Periodo Medio(s)`) as maximo FROM prueba2.arousa_wave_marea_sol
group by 2
union all
SELECT `Periodo de Pico(s)`, year(`Fecha (GMT)`)*100+month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Fecha,month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Mes, avg(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as Promedio, variance(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as Varianza, stddev(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as Desviacion_tipica, std(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as Desviacion_estandar, min(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as Minimo, max(`Periodo de Pico(s)`) as maximo FROM prueba2.arousa_wave_marea_sol
group by 2
union all
SELECT `Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`, year(`Fecha (GMT)`)*100+month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Fecha,month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Mes, avg(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as Promedio, variance(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as Varianza, stddev(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as Desviacion_tipica, std(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as Desviacion_estandar, min(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as Minimo, max(`Direcc Media de Proced(0=N,90=E)`) as maximo FROM prueba2.arousa_wave_marea_sol
group by 2
union all
SELECT `Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`, year(`Fecha (GMT)`)*100+month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Fecha,month(`Fecha (GMT)`) as Mes, avg(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as Promedio, variance(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as Varianza, stddev(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as Desviacion_tipica, std(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as Desviacion_estandar, min(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as Minimo, max(`Mar de fondo 1:  Altura signif Espectral(m)`) as maximo FROM prueba2.arousa_wave_marea_sol
group by 2
```

Comment: una consulta te va a traer siempre los valores de los registros, no los nombres de los campos. Esos los tienes ya al definir la consulta... eso es lo que quieres?